# Help me identify this insect from Bangladesh

Tags: zoology, species-identification, entomology

I have seen this insect flying literally everywhere in Dhaka city (Bangladesh) over the last two months. It's small -- around 1-1.5 inches long. It's not an agile flyer and can be easily grabbed by hand during flight.

[image]
[image]

Comment: woah wonderful specimen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is actually the flying adult of a scale insect (superfamily [Coccoidea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_insect)). Specifically, this appears to be some species of the genus **Drosicha**.

Here is a picture resembling your specimen:

[image: https://www.flickr.com/photos/itchydogimages/8944327442]

Source: [John Horstman](https://www.flickr.com/photos/itchydogimages/8944327442)

And another from Vietnam that looks very similar:

[image: drosicha]

Source: [Dan Doucette](http://www.projectnoah.org/spottings/10235360)

I can only find info on a closely related species, *Drosicha corpulenta*, and here's a [tree of related species](http://www.catalogueoflife.org/annual-checklist/2011/search/all/key/drosicha/match/1).

[Scalenet](http://scalenet.info/catalogue/drosicha/) provides numerous keys and references that could be useful for positively IDing this specimen.

I will keep searching for more details, but this might be the best you get without asking a scale insect expert.

Comment: Female looks very different. https://flic.kr/p/cysZ9S