# Identify round, green, flying insect with spikes in South Carolina (USA)

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

The tables have turned -- *I* need some help IDing an insect:

I've been unable to identify an insect that I came across about 6 years ago in South Carolina (USA).

We were doing a vegetation survey in a northern South Carolina forest when I felt a pinch (or bite) feeling on my hand. When I looked down a seemingly nearly round insect was at the site of the pain but flew away shortly after.

I have no photo of the insect, unfortunately, but I can best describe it as being light green, round (0.5-0.75 cm diameter) and shaped like a deep (i.e., slightly recessed) dinner plate with a ring of soft spikes around the perimeter of the slightly raised edges of its round body. I unfortunately have no recollection of the head or wings.

Here is a rough sketch of what I remember:

[image]

The spikes were very reminiscent of the backside of some adult scale insects (such as [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/57694/16866)) [seen below].

[image]

Given it's similarity to some scale insects, I've always assumed it was some species in the [Coccoideae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_insect) superfamily, but I have never been able to find a matching species.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The only green spikey insect I've found to date is [*Spissistilus*](https://bugguide.net/node/view/269873/bgimage)